# Implement a custom COM interface in Java

Tags: c#, java, com, interface

I need to pull some data from Java into C#. I am already exposing my C# classes via COM. So I thought a good way to pull data from Java would be to expose `IReadStream` from C# and implement `IReadStream` in Java. I can then send an instance of the implementation as a parameter to C# so that I can call `IReadStream.Read` in C#.

How do I implement a custom COM interface in Java?

Comment: You may have to use JNI/JNA to expose a C++ COM interface that your C# class can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went for named pipes in the end.

On the java side I write into a named pipe (served from the c# side). In c# i should now be able to read from the named pipe. As long as the Read operation is blocking it should be the same as pulling data from java.

See http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/dotnetnamedpipespart1.aspx for a c# wrapper around the Named pipes api calls.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it supports this direction, but [Jacob](http://jacob-project.wiki.sourceforge.net/) is a Java COM Bridge that's frequently mentioned.

Also, using [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/) to run the Java code might make the task significantly easier.

Comment: thanks, i know about jacob. don't think it support what i want to do

Answer (score 0):

Using COM sounds overly messy whats wrong with exposing your c# code via a socket and have java suck that down.