# java-COM interop: Implement COM interface in Java

Tags: java, windows, com, native

How can I implement a vtable COM interface in java?

In the old days, I'd use the Microsft JVM, which had built in java-COM interop. What's the equivalent for a modern JRE?

Answers to a similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696442/how-to-implement-a-custom-com-interface-in-java) proposed JACOB. I've looked at JACOB, but that is based on IDispatch, and is aimed at controlling Automation serers. The COM interfaces I need are custom vtable (extend IUnknown), e.g. IPersistStream, IOleWindow, IContextMenu etc.

For my use case, I could implement all the COM specifics in JNI, and have the JNI layer call corresponding interfaces in java. But I'm hoping for a less painful solution.

It's for an open source project, so open source alternatives are preferred.

EDIT: Com4j looks promising. Looking through the available docs, it doesn't seem to support registering a IClassFactory so the COM object (in java) can be instantiated by non-java clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Com4J](https://com4j.dev.java.net/tutorial.html) may be what you need. From the homepage:

> Binds directly to the vtable interface
>   (not IDispatch) for improved
>   performance and broader support for
>   more COM interfaces.

Comment: Thanks for this. This was what I was looking for. I've looked through the docs and it looks great - just one thing missing - it doesn't seem to support providing a IClassFactory so the COM object (implemented in java) can be instantiated through COM.