# Import custom protocol into MS Excel / Access

Tags: java, excel, http, ms-access, odbc

I have a standalone Java application capable of replaying a time series of data records.  Communication with the server is performed using a bespoke binary wire protocol over TCP/IP.

We have a requirement to be able to easily import data records from this application into MS Excel / Access and I am interested in the recommended way to do this.

One idea we're exploring is to write a web "wrapper" service (also in Java) that will communicate with the underlying server and then translate the binary data into a more friendly text format for consumption by Excel / Access.  However, the drawback here is that we lose any type information associated with each field in a given record.

I've briefly looked into writing custom ODBC / OleDB drivers but this seems complex and is probably overkill for what we're trying to achieve.

Can anyone recommend any other approaches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about xlloop? http://xlloop.sourceforge.net/
Uses an Excel plugin to connect to a function server, where you can create your own functions.

Comment: Thanks; looks promising - I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You may connect with an Access Database via the JDBC/ODBC Bridge driver.

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I'm asking: I want to connect to the Java application from MS Access / Excel, not the other way round.

Comment: Ok. I think you can use an ebedded database as a mediator. For instance use SQLLite or another embeddet Database  and read with Access or Excel via ODBC from this one.

Answer (score 0):

From your previous comments I assume that you need to serve dynamic/changing data. If that is the case then take maybe the [IRtdServer interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.irtdserver%28office.11%29.aspx) and [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/285339/en-us) referring to Excel. Its a COM Interface so you probably will need something like [Com4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889984/java-com-interop-implement-com-interface-in-java)