# Accessing MS CryptoAPI with java

Tags: java, sha256, cryptoapi, mscapi

I was trying to make good use of the [MS CAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_CryptoAPI), and stumped into a great mischief... The SunMSCapi provider only, hmm, provides, per lack of better word, at least for signature, the following algorithms:

- MD2withRSA
- MD5withRSA
- SHA1withRSA

And I am not eager to make use of algorithms such **`GOST3411withECGOST3410`**, or **`RIPEMD128withRSA`**, that BouncyCastle makes use, but it would be nice, and in this particular case, quite important if not essential, to be able to sign in, at least, the **`SHA256withRSA`** algorithm... (the 512 and so on and ECDSA encryption, would be a big plus, but i don't expect that much).

I am trying to find an alternative, but only found [this wrapper](http://pheox.com/products/jcapi/), which looks fine, but I have to dig it a little more.

Does anyone knows another way, wrapper or provider to access mscapi (cryptoapi)?

---

Related:

- SunMSCapi doc:
  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunMSCAPI
- Request for **`SHA256withRSA`**:
  https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6753664

Comment: Both provided links doesn't work on my system.

Comment: Thanks to Matej it was corrected

Comment: If Pheox is selling a working solution, I suppose that's your best option - considering it's worth the price for you.

Comment: I was searching for something that I can improve, I can maintain. It stands as a black box, for me.

Comment: Make a COM wrapper in Jython? Or COM4J or JACOB: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889984/java-com-interop-implement-com-interface-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [RSA bsafe share](https://community.emc.com/community/edn/rsashare) which supports RSA with SHA-256.

Answer (score 1):

Java is cross platform, if you choose SunMSCapi, you can only run on windows with JDK 6+, and if want SHA256withRSA, you need run on JDK7+, it is there.
check code [RSASignature.SHA256](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/security/mscapi/RSASignature.java#RSASignature.SHA256)

Comment: You see, I make use of it, is one of my sources.

Comment: I use MS-CAPICOM, PKCS11 and PKCS12