# Plug-in interface design for unbiased interface to allow it to be used by any programming language

Tags: c++, plugins, com

I am designing a plug-in interface to my application and I want to allow the users to be able to implement this plug-in interface in any language they want to. so I thought about COM objects is that a right decision? and why?

Note:
My application is a C++ application written in VC++2005.

Comment: Is it something like anyone who implements the interface can write a dll that u can load dynamically?

Comment: "Any language" is a rather wide range, covering everything from Ada to [Whitespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language)). I doubt that you want *that* :)

Comment: I basically want to support unmanaged C++, managed C++, VB, C# and maybe java. Also I want to allow to load more than plug-in at the same time.

Comment: Involving java implies that COM is not an option. Otherwise if you want to use 'dot net languages' com is the only option if your binary is written in native C/C++.

Comment: Yes, COM sounds like the right way to go.

Comment: I thought COM is a good option as even MS is using it in SharePoint for some internal EBS interface. but I want to make sure I can load more than one COM object at the same time.

Comment: @Abhinav: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889984/java-com-interop-implement-com-interface-in-java for info on how to use COM from Java.

Comment: I hate when Java does that. Shakes my deep rooted disrespect for the language. @Gabe - thanks for the info man, i dint know that :-p

Answer (score 0):

If it is really a plugin that you need call some of the plugin functions from your C++ application, I don't think you can do it with COM for those scripting language like php or javascript (unless you create an interpreter). But if it is something like scripting/automation, that you rely on your plugin to call functions provided by your application, COM is the helpful.